# Jasmine spy on calling a method on variable object

Tags: jasmine

Consider this:

```
function () {
  var toast = new Toaster.ToastMessage({
    title: Resources.Localised.COPY_Success,
    message: Resources.Localised.COPY_CaseSavedSuccess,
    severity: Toaster.ToastSeverity.Success,
    position: Toaster.ToastPosition.TopRight
  });

  toast.show();
}
```

In jasmine, is there a way to verify show() is called?  I'm thinking not, actually it makes sense that it wouldn't.

I have no access to the variable toast.

`spyOn(Toaster.ToastMessage, "show");` does not work.
I've played with `createSpyObj (jasmine.createSpyObj('Toaster.ToastMessage', ['show']);)` without success.

Thanks.

Comment: can you not `return` something from the function? like a `boolean` value or even an `integer` `0` or `1` to indicate success or failure?

Comment: Yep, though my perspective here was I was TDD'ing the behaviour I wanted the method to have.  In C# I'd be mocking a property or constructor in this situation, so I'm thinking better off making my toaster a property for now.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to spy on the `prototype` of `Toaster.ToastMessage`:

```
spyOn(Toaster.ToastMessage.prototype, "show")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
spyOn(Toaster.ToastMessage, "show");
```

and then after the "show" method is executed use:

```
expect(Toaster.ToastMessage.show).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```